# unable to run script with owners privileges even after setuid bit is set and o+rx is provided

Tags: linux, setuid

unable to run script with owners privileges even after setuid bit is set and o+rx is provided

Hi,
I have created a script with user Shyam and provided r-x to other and set the setuid bit for this file.

-rwsrwxr-x. 1 shyam shyam 53 Nov 26 14:43 shyam.sh

Script contains below :

echo Hello $USER

echo `date` Hello $USER >> test.txt

shyam is able to run this but when yesh user runs the script 1st line gets executed but on 2nd line it says permission denied.
Attaching a screenshot with some details. 
I am not sure what am I missing here in order to achieve -> yesh to successfully run the entire script. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAQpG.png)

Comment: You should ask this question on super-user. It is not a programming question.
https://superuser.com/

Comment: Setuid bits are ignored on scripts. Run the script with `sudo -u shyam`.

Comment: thanks Alex that helped :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this has been [asked and answered before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/), the gist being:

> Linux ignores the setuid bit on all interpreted executables (i.e. executables starting with a #! line). The [comp.unix.questions FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html) explains the security problems with setuid shell scripts. These problems are of two kinds: shebang-related and shell-related; I go into more details below.